# Forms stucks when sending http request [c#]

Tags: c#, http, get, request

Hi i have a problem with my code. When program run first time its sending a http request to my server on arduino. First reqest is always very slow and my form stucks for 10-20 seconds. Next requests are working great there is a problem only with first request and when i turn off my server and trying to request. There is my requesting function (sry for my English) :

```
    private string SubmitData(string postData)
    {
        try
        {
            string req = "";
            req = "http://" + ip + "/" + postData;


            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(req);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

            String rower = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();
            return rower;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "ERR";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to avoid my problem :). Is there any way to set the max time to wait for response ? Or how to send my requests without having "stuck problem" ?

Comment: Avoiding "unresponsive GUI" can only be done by moving code for the communication stuff in another thread (i.e. BackgroundWorker). Of course you can reduce HttpWebRequest.Timeout but then you will have no success with your 1st request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(would post this as comment, but is not cool enough...)

I cannot answer to why the first request is slow, but are you sure it is not the server that is slow the first time?

If you want to limit the maximum waiting time, you may change the timeout value

```
WebRequest.Timeout = 5000; // Units of ms
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx 'Descendant classes signal a timeout by throwing a WebException with the Status field set to WebExceptionStatus.Timeout. '